# python3 + how to open files while file that opened created with owner and group on the fly

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

here is simple example when I wrote the list - some_list in file test.txt

```
    with open('/home/moon/test.txt', 'w') as f:
        print(some_list, file=f)
        f.close()
```

the file above created with owner and group `root:root`

is it possible to create the same file with specific owner and group as `moon:san` instead of `root:root`

the other choice is of course to create the file first under `/home/moon/test.txt` and then change the owner as moon and group as san , and then use the code that open the file

Comment: You don't need `f.close()` when you use `with` -- the whole point is that it automatically closes it for you.

Comment: Files are always created with the owner and group of the process that's running the program. The root user can use `os.chown()` to change the ownership.

Answer (score 0):

No, the only option is to create a file under the current user and then change the file owner to another user. So the code would be something like:

```
import os

file_path = '/path/to/file.txt'

with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
    f.write('some text')

uid = 1000
gid = 1000

os.chown(file_path, uid, gid)
```

where `uid` and `gid` are user id and group id of desired user and its group.

But, if you don't want to write this "chown" code every time, there are some options:

1. Move it to a function along with writing to file:

```
import os

def write_to_file_with_ownership(file_path, text, uid=1000, gid=1000):
    with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(text)

    os.chown(file_path, uid, gid)

write_to_file_with_ownership('/home/artem/test.txt', 'some text', uid=999, gid=999)
```

2. Create your own context manager that will encapsulate changing ownership logic:

```
import os
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def open_with_ownership(file_path_, uid=1000, gid=1000):
    f_ = open(file_path_, 'w')
    try:
        yield f_
    finally:
        f_.close()
        os.chown(file_path_, uid, gid)


file_path = '/home/artem/test.txt'
with open_with_ownership(file_path, uid=999, gid=999) as f:
    f.write('some text')
```

**Notes:**

- If you want the script to change file attributes (like ownership) - you need to run the script under an user with super user permissions, e.g. root.
- If you know only user name, like `moon`, in order to determine gid and uid run this command:

```
$ id moon
```

and you will see something like that (for artem in my case):

```
$ id artem
uid=1000(artem) gid=1000(artem)
```

- If you use a function where you will write to file and change permissions - this option works, but it breaks [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) a bit, so the best practice is to have 3 functions: the first one writes to a file, the second one changes the file's attributes, and the third one - is something like a manager function which invokes the first and the second functions in a proper order. This principle is needed to long-term code support, to have it easy and convenient for a developer.